# trouble implementing javascript in aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Im new to asp.net and javascript. Fairly educated about html and css. Im trying to complete my asp.net project but having problem with implementing javascript in my aspx page. im trying to create parallax scrolling using stellar.js but its not working.

here is the javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.stellar.js"></script>


<script>
$.stellar({
scrollProperty: 'scroll',
});
</script>
```

and i have included this line in the head section of my home.aspx page

```
 <script src="JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but it dosent work. Though it works fine in a simple html page.

Ps- im not using master page or content place holder in this page. It purely consists of html tags, not even one asp tool.

here's the content of home.aspx, if that helps. (and yes im a newbie)

```
           <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="home.aspx.cs" Inherits="home" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title>Bon Voyage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>



    <div class="header">

   <p><span style="color:Red; font-family:myFirstFont;">B</span>on <span style="color:Red; font-family:myFirstFont;">V</span>oyage</p>

   <a href="#">HOME</a>
   <a href="#aaa" >HOLIDAYS</a>
   <a href="#">FLIGHT</a>
   <a href="#">HOTELS</a>
   <a href="#">BUS</a>
   <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
   <a href="#"  style="padding-right:130px;">CONTACT US</a>
   <a href="login.aspx" style="margin-left:200px; font-size:16px;">LOGIN</a>



   </div>


   <div id="container">

   <div class="body1" >
   <div class="onbody1">
   <img class="icon" src="airplane-57-xxl.png"></img>
   <hr width="62%" align="left"><p class="name">Bon Voyage</p>&nbsp;<hr width="62%" align="left">
   <p class="desc">Your one stop shop for all your travelling needs.</p>
   </div>

   </div>

   <div class="body2" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.3">
   <p >asdadas</p>


   </div>

   <div class="body3">
   <p id="aaa">asdadas</p>


   </div>


   </div> 



   </body>
```

and the css

```
    body
    {
        width: 100%;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: myFirstFont;
        src: url(chocolate_hippo.ttf);
    }

    .header{
        position:fixed;
        background-color: #333333;
        height:70px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align:right;
        line-height: 70px;

        z-index:3;


    }

    .header a{
          text-decoration:none;
          color: white;
          font-weight: 100;
          padding-right:20px;


    }

    .header a:hover{color:#909090 ;}


    .header p
    {
        float:left;
        padding-right:150px;
        font-family: myFirstFont;
        color:White;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:35px;
        margin-left:12px;
    }



    /*--------Style for home page----------*/

    .body1
    {
        background-image: url('imageedit_4_6588588848.jpg');
        height:1000px;
        background-size:100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        background-attachment:fixed;
    }

    .icon
    {
        margin-top:160px;
        margin-bottom:30px;
        margin-left:550px;
        height:200px;
        width:200px;
        border:3px solid white;
        border-radius:50%;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-property: transform;
        opacity:0.9;

    }


    .icon:hover {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        border:8px solid white;
        border-radius:1px;
    }

    .name
    {
        color:White;
        font-size:70px;
        opacity:0.8;
        margin-left:456px;
        margin-top:20px;
        border-top:2px solid white;
        border-bottom:2px solid white;
       -o-transition:background 0.8s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition:background 0.8s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: background 0.8s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: background 0.8s ease-in-out;

    }



    .desc
    {
       font-size:30px;
        margin-left:350px;
        margin-top:20px;
        color:White;
        opacity:0.9;
    }

    .body2
    {
         background-attachment:fixed;
        height:500px;
        background-image: url('page-4_img01_original.jpg');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:100%;
    }

    .body3
    {
        height:600px;


    }
```

Thanks in advance for all of yours answers.

Comment: Open developer tools of browser (F12) do you see any errors in console tab?

Comment: Btw as per their document they say run steller again the element first so you need to create an element or run it on window: $(window).stellar();
// or:
$('#main').stellar();

Comment: make sure you specify the corect path in the src

Comment: Zaki, yes there is an error in console, which says:                         JScript.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: And alex all the files are in same folder, so i guess the path is not the problem.

Comment: @PrinceDey see Samira's answer

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to close the type attribute in first line

Comment: Just noticed that, but it is closed in the main page so... :'(

Comment: is your "jquery.stellar.js" file is in the same folder of your project,if it's not you should address it exactly

Comment: Yup they are in the same folder.